# How to use a variable in a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, ubuntu

I am editting/extending my firewall bash script on ubuntu dedicated server.

The code below is just an excerpt.
The purpose below is to reroute/open for some IPs my (http, ftp, telnet and ssh) ports for/to 3 boxes.

The problem is that I want to use variables in a variable.
So `--dport ${i}_${j}_port_ext` is correctly replaced by f.i. `--dport box0_http_port_ext` but is not seen as a variable (of course). Actually, what I want should be `--dport $box0_http_port_ext` (mind the `$` at the beginning)

I tried several things f.i. `--dport ${${i}_${j}_port_ext}` or `--dport $(${i}_${j}_port_ext)` but that is not good.

```
box0_http_port_ext="8080"
box0_ftp_port_ext="21"
box0_telnet_port_ext="23"
box0_ssh_port_ext="22"
#
allow_box0_http_port_ip="1.2.3.4 99.98.97.96 55.56.57.58"
allow_box0_ftp_port_ip="1.2.3.4 55.56.57.58"
allow_box0_telnet_port_ip="55.56.57.58"
allow_box0_ssh_port_ip="1.2.3.4"
#
for i in box0 box1 box2
do
  for j in http ftp telnet ssh
  do   
    for ips in $allow_${i}_${j}_port_ip
    do
      $IPTABLES -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i $LAN_IFACE -s $ips --dport ${i}_${j}_port_ext -j DNAT --to-destination ${i}_ip:${i}_${j}_port_int
    done
  done
done
```

Please do not look at the code because it is an excerpt and thus not complete.
The question is: how to code `--dport $box0_http_port_ext` by making use of `$i` for *box0* and `$j` for *http*. Keeping in mind that `$i` also can be *box1/box2* and `$j` also can be replaced by *ftp/telnet/ssh*.

Comment: @ni_hao please share the solution once you got it fixed.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using an ***Indirect Variable Reference*** (See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver2.html#EX78)

This is available in *Bash Version 2* and above, using a `!` before the variable name, inside the `${ }`.

```
name=${i}_${j}_port_ext
echo ${!name}
```

***Working example:***

```
#!/bin/bash
i=box0
j=http

box0_http_port_ext="hello1"
box2_telnet_port_ext="hello2"

name=${i}_${j}_port_ext
echo "varname: $name   value: ${!name}"

i="box2"
j="telnet"
name="${i}_${j}_port_ext"
echo "varname: $name   value: ${!name}"
```

***Output***:

```
varname: box0_http_port_ext   value: hello1
varname: box2_telnet_port_ext   value: hello2
```

In the above example `$name` returns the sting `box0_http_port_ext`, which is the name of the initial variable. This is equivalent to ${name}. The `!` operator evaluates the string to its right side as a variable name, and returns the value that is stored in the variable. So `${!name}` returns the value of `${box0_http_port_ext}` which is `hello1`.

Unfortunately bash does not support multi-dimensional arrays, but this trick can be used instead.

*The difference from the other answer is that `$i_$j_port_ext` is changed to `${i}_${j}_port_ext` so that bash knows where the name of the variable ends.*

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
varname=${i}_${j}_port_ext
... --dport ${!varname} ...
```

Note the ! inside the `${}`

Edited: good point from @user000001 about delimiting the i/j variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to escape `_` character in the script

```
--dport $i\_$j\_port\_ext
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks you helped me a lot.

BTW, I did notice the difference between f.i. $name and {!name}. $name gives the name of the variable, where ${!name} the contents of the variable gives. Is that the only explanation?

Regarding the (good) comments to my question i.r.t. the above mentioned excerpt, this is working for me:

```
for i in box0 box1 box2
do
  for j in http ftp telnet ssh
  do
    ALLOWED_IPS=allow_${i}_${j}_port_ip
    for ips in ${!ALLOWED_IPS}; do
    do
      PORT_EXT=${i}_${j}_port_ext; PORT_INT=${i}_${j}_port_int; IP=${i}_ip
      $IPTABLES -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i $LAN_IFACE -s $ips --dport ${!PORT_EXT} -j DNAT --to-destination ${!IP}:${!PORT_INT}
    done
  done
done
```